# XPath variables in lxml

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, lxml

I want to use [XPath variables](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html) to match a user-defined tag and avoid XPath injection vulnerabilities. I have tried

```
from lxml import etree
etree.fromstring('<div><p>Hello</p></div>').xpath('.//$var', var='p')
```

but I get

```
XPathEvalError: Invalid expression
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want to get element just by tag name?

Comment: My XPath expression is more complicated than the above - I want to find a specific tag in particular location(s) in the tree. The tag name is not known in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can use a variable to represent a node in an expression. It has to be a literal QName. But you can use a wildcard and a predicate. The following works: `etree.fromstring('<div><p>Hello</p></div>').xpath('.//*[local-name() = $var]', var='p')`.

Comment: You can try to resolve it with simple `Python` variables: `tag = "p"`, `expr = "//%s[text()='Hello']" % tag` and then use it as `etree.fromstring('<div><p>Hello</p></div>').xpath(expr)[0]`

Comment: @Andersson the point of using `$var` is to avoid the possibility of XPath injection which occurs with normal string substitution.

Comment: @mzjn ah, thanks! You should post that as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a variable as the [node test](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-tests) part of a location step in an expression. It has to be a literal name. But you can use a wildcard and a predicate. The following works:

```
etree.fromstring('<div><p>Hello</p></div>').xpath('.//*[loca‌​l-name() = $var]', var='p')
```