# Xpath: Querying the sibling of an element which contains another element that has specific text

Tags: python, loops, xpath

I have the following HTML, redacted without changing any of the structure or substance:

```
<a name="Name"></a>
<a name="FEATURE_Name"></a>
<span class="class">
  <nobr>some text <b>Name</b> as  
    <nobr>
      <a href="a.big.complicated.href">kindOfObject</a>
    </nobr>
    (SOMETECHNOBABBLE=protontorpedoes);
  </nobr>
</span>
<blockquote>Further (Details)</blockquote>
```

This structure is repeated hundreds of times.

Now, I have a list of strings that correspond to each 'Name' already pulled together from elsewhere in the document, because it was easy to figure out how to get at those with an Xpath query. What I would like to do is iterate through that list, and for each one of the structures shown above, grab the string "kindOfObject" from the block whose Name matches the name of the list index I am currently on.

This is the xpath query I tried:

```
tree.xpath("//nobr/b[contains(text(), i)]/following-sibling::nobr/a/text()")
```

However, this returns ALL of the kindOfObject values for each index. What I want to be able to do is get each one so that I can then match them up into key:value pairs in a dictionary. So, when i is Name1, my query retrieves only the kindOfObject value from the block whose Name is Name1. Then when i is Name2, it gets the kindOfObject value that matches that, and so on.

Looking at Thomas Kison's response below, I tried running the Xpath query putting a single Name in place of 'i' and got the matching kindOfObject and nothing else. This would imply that it is more iterator that is the problem. This was the loop I'd written just to test that I was getting the right information:

```
for i in Names:
    kindOfObject = tree.xpath("//nobr/b[contains(text(), i)]/following-sibling::nobr/a/text()")
    print(kindOfObject)
```

I would expect this to print each `kindOfObject` once, when its relevant `i` was passed into the Xpath query, but this yields the complete list of `kindOfObject` for each index.

Comment: First, `b[contains(text(), i)]` has no meaning unless there is an `i` element child of `b` element. Second, even after correcting the expression doesn't seem posible to get your informed results unless the document schema is different from your sample (there are more `nobr` elements siblings of `b` element) or the expression is not the same (you are using `following` axis instead)

Comment: Now is clear that your problem is how to pass variables to your python XPath engine. If this is hopely `lxml` then this is the relevant part of the documentation https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#the-xpath-method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath variables in lxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42783305/xpath-variables-in-lxml)

Answer (score 0):

The Statement seems to be correct

```xml
<a name="Name"></a>
<a name="FEATURE_Name"></a>
<span class="class">
  <nobr>some text <b>Name1</b> as  
    <nobr>
      <a href="a.big.complicated.href">kindOfObject1</a>
    </nobr>
    (SOMETECHNOBABBLE=protontorpedoes);
  </nobr>
  <nobr>some text <b>Name2</b> as  
    <nobr>
      <a href="a.big.complicated.href">kindOfObject2</a>
    </nobr>
    (SOMETECHNOBABBLE=protontorpedoes);
  </nobr>
</span>
<blockquote>Further (Details)</blockquote>
```

`//nobr/b[contains(text(), "Name1")]/following-sibling::nobr/a/text()`

will return kindOfObject1

`//nobr/b[contains(text(), "Name2")]/following-sibling::nobr/a/text()`

will return kindOfObject2